# Adding an active class with JQuery should work like this, right?

Tags: jquery

OK, I'm going crazy here! Why won't this work!! I'm trying to add a class of active to top level menu navigation... so for my menu that would be the About, News, Business, etc... buttons. Here is the html for the menu:

```
<ul id="topnavtwo">
   <li>
       <a href="/CoVPrototype/about.php" class="about_pg">About Vancouver</a>
            <div class="sub">
                <ul class="lonesome_group">

                    <li><h2><a href="#">History</a></h2></li>
                    <div class="lonesome_link_ul"><hr /></div>
                    <li><h2><a href="#">Geography</a></h2></li>
                    <div class="lonesome_link_ul"><hr /></div>
                    <li><h2><a href="#">Things To Do</a></h2></li>
                    <div class="lonesome_link_ul"><hr /></div>
                    <li><h2><a href="#">Population</a></h2></li>
                    <div class="lonesome_link_ul"><hr /></div>
                    <li><h2><a href="#">Weather</a></h2></li>
                    <div class="lonesome_link_ul"><hr /></div>
                    <li><h2><a href="#">Education</a></h2></li>
                    <div class="lonesome_link_ul"><hr /></div>
                    <li><h2><a href="#">Health</a></h2></li>
                    <div class="lonesome_link_ul"><hr /></div>
                    <li><h2><a href="#">Cemetery</a></h2></li>
                    <div class="lonesome_link_ul"><hr /></div>
                </ul>
                <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="/CoVPrototype/news.php" class="news_pg">In The News</a>
            <div class="sub">
                    <ul style="width: 160px;">
                        <li><h2><a href="#">Special Events</a></h2></li>
                        <div class="short_ul"><hr /></div>
                        <li><h2><a href="#">Media Resources</a></h2></li>
                        <div class="short_ul"><hr /></div>
                        <li><h2><a href="#">Archive</a></h2></li>
                        <div class="short_ul"><hr /></div>
                    </ul>
                </div>
        </li>

<!--Mega Menu Section-->
            <a href="/CoVPrototype/business.php" class="doing_business_pg">Doing Business</a>
              <div class="sub_bus">
                    <ul class="lonesome_group">

                        <li><h2><a href="#">Economic Development</a></h2></li>
                        <div class="lonesome_link_ul"><hr /></div>
                        <li><h2><a href="#">Taxes</a></h2></li>
                        <div class="lonesome_link_ul"><hr /></div>
                    </ul>

                    <ul style="width: 160px;">
                        <li><h2>Business Assistance</h2></li>
                        <div class="short_ul"><hr /></div>
                        <li><a href="#">Doing Business With The City</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Starting a new Business</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Incentives</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Information and Rules</a></li>
                    </ul>

                    <ul style="width: 160px;">
                        <li><h2>Liscence And Permits</h2></li>
                        <div class="short_ul"><hr /></div>
                        <li><a href="#">Types of Business Licenses</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Apply for Business License</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Pay &amp; Manage Business </a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">License</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">TV, Radio &amp; Film</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Retail Sidewalk</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Permits</a></li>
                    </ul>

                    <ul style="width: 160px;">
                        <li><h2>Opportunities With<br /><br /><br /><br />The City</h2></li>
                        <div class="short_ul"><hr /></div>
                        <li><a href="#">Bids</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Contacts Awarded</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Ethical Purchasing Policy</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Purchase Order Items</a></li>
                    </ul>

                     <ul style="width: 160px;">
                        <li><h2>Walking</h2></li>
                        <div class="short_ul"><hr /></div>
                        <li><a href="#">Routes &amp; Maps</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Neighbourhoods</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Green Streets</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Initiatives</a></li>
                    </ul>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

And my JQuery is like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#topnavtwo li a').click(function() {
          $('topnavtwo li a').addClass('active');
        });
     });
    </script>
```

I don't get it, shouldn't this work??!!

Comment: Expecting a waterfall of answers containing #'es.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this should work (missing hash):

```
$('#topnavtwo li a').addClass('active');
```

Comment: Thanks for this... although I'm sure everyone else's suggestions would work this one worked for me...I'm just applying it to each page with a more direct route $('#topnavtwo li a about_pg').addClass('active'); for the about page and $('#topnavtwo li a' gov_pg).addClass('active'); for the government page. I'm sure this is the long route...but it's working for me :) Thank's everyone!!

Answer (score 6):

You're missing the '#' in the 2nd selector.

You should replace the 2nd selector with $(this)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#topnavtwo li a').click(function() {
          $(this).addClass('active');
        });
     });
    </script>
```

Comment: Not just could, but should!  Because it's inside a click handler function, `$(this)` refers to the link that got clicked - adding a class to this (one) link is probably what you want.  `$(#topnavtwo li a)` refers to _every single anchor tag inside #topnavtwo_ - and you probably don't want to add a class to all of them at once...

Comment: I'll buy that. Thanks @Xavier.

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#topnavtwo li a').click(function() {
        $('#topnavtwo li a').addClass('active'); // Look at this line
        // Or replace it with (without the //):
        // $(this).addClass('active');
    });
});
</script>
```

See the comment in the click handler.

Answer (score 0):

you forgot a # in the 4th line of your script

Answer (score 0):

To help in the progress a bit without #s.

Instead asking it first you can simply check your code by Firebug (in Firefox) or in the developer menu in Chrome.

Another solution if you alert something after all events in javascript like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    alert("document.ready.function");
    $('#topnavtwo li a').click(function() {
    alert("the click was okay");
        $('topnavtwo li a').addClass('active');
        alert("a has class active");
    });
});
</script>
```

So you can see when the code broke.
Or later you can try and catch everything.

```
try {
var tmp = doSomething();
if (tmp == something.errorCondition)
throw new Error("Error condition in X");
} catch(err) {
//handle ((err && err.message) || err.toString())
}
```

Comment: All this error handling wouldn't expose the error. Though the selector is incorrect for this scenario, the code is legit.

Comment: Thank you all so much for such quick replies!! Unfortunately I haven't found the solution yet... I tried: <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    alert("document.ready.function");
    $('#topnavtwo li a').click(function() {
    alert("the click was okay");
        $('topnavtwo li a').addClass('active');
        alert("a has class active");
    });
});
</script>
and saw that yes the active class is being added... however, it doesn't seem to stick around! I also have this code for a different menu... is it possible that this is affecting it? It's for an accordion menu

Comment: Here's the code:
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#accordion li').children('ul').hide();
    $('.history_heading').parent().addClass('active').find('ul').show();

    $('#accordion a').click(function() {

        $(this).parent().siblings('.active').removeClass('active').find('ul').slideUp('fast');

        if ($(this).parent().hasClass('active')) {
            $(this).next('ul').slideUp('fast');
            $(this).parent().removeClass('active');
        } else {
            $(this).next('ul').slideDown('fast');
            $(this).parent().addClass('active');
        }

    });

});